# bind9 not recursing when configured to do so

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

A new bind server is not returning recursive domains. What I have found so far:

When a client queries the server, I can see the recursive queries sent to the forwarders enter and leave using tcpdump, and also the root servers being queried.

I have used a known good configuration, so the problem must be specific to the new server setup. One thing that is different from the previous servers and this one, is that previous servers had a single interface, while this one resolves via a different interface than the clients it is serving.

I can perform DNS lookups locally from the server if I specify another DNS server, including my forwarders.

The local server serves local domains successfully.

The logs do not show any errors that would suggest a configuration error.

Can someone salve my sanity?

Example local nslookup from the server from a client query:

```
:~$ nslookup
> google.com
Server:         <isp-dns-ip>
Address:        <isp-dns-ip>#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.213.14
Name:   google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4009:816::200e
> server 127.0.0.1
Default server: 127.0.0.1
Address: 127.0.0.1#53
> google.com
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find google.com: SERVFAIL
> wdcds01.home.int
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Name:   wdcds01.home.int
Address: 192.168.76.100
```

My options config ( is filtered; actual ip address in config):

```
acl "trusted"{
        localnets;
        127.0.0.1;
        192.168.0.0/24;
        192.168.76.0/24;
        192.168.251.0/24;
        172.22.15.0/27;
        };
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    dnssec-validation auto;
    recursion yes;
    querylog yes;

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on port 53 { any; };

    forwarders {
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;
        <isp-dns-ip>;
        192.168.76.100;
        };
    allow-query-cache {trusted;};
    allow-query {trusted;};
    allow-recursion {trusted;};
    forward first;
};
```

Example log file entries:

```
:~$ tail /var/log/named/named.log 
07-Sep-2022 09:14:17.443 fetch: ./DNSKEY
07-Sep-2022 09:29:30.217 obtaining root key for view _default from '/etc/bind/bind.keys'
07-Sep-2022 09:29:30.217 dnssec-validation auto: WARNING: root zone key not found
07-Sep-2022 09:29:30.217 using built-in root key for view _default
07-Sep-2022 09:29:30.225 fetch: ./DNSKEY
07-Sep-2022 09:29:34.877 fetch: google.com/A
07-Sep-2022 09:29:34.905 fetch: com/DS
07-Sep-2022 09:29:35.781 fetch: google.com/AAAA
07-Sep-2022 09:29:38.098 fetch: google.com/A
07-Sep-2022 09:29:38.130 fetch: google.com/AAAA
:~$ tail /var/log/named/querylog 
07-Sep-2022 09:23:32.678 client @0x7f93f800a3e0 192.168.76.139#37679 (249.76.168.192.in-addr.arpa): query: 249.76.168.192.in-addr.arpa IN PTR + (192.168.76.1)
07-Sep-2022 09:23:32.678 client @0x7f93f800a3e0 192.168.76.139#37679 (250.76.168.192.in-addr.arpa): query: 250.76.168.192.in-addr.arpa IN PTR + (192.168.76.1)
07-Sep-2022 09:23:32.682 client @0x7f93f800a3e0 192.168.76.139#37679 (251.76.168.192.in-addr.arpa): query: 251.76.168.192.in-addr.arpa IN PTR + (192.168.76.1)
07-Sep-2022 09:23:32.682 client @0x7f93f800a3e0 192.168.76.139#37679 (252.76.168.192.in-addr.arpa): query: 252.76.168.192.in-addr.arpa IN PTR + (192.168.76.1)
07-Sep-2022 09:23:32.686 client @0x7f93f800a3e0 192.168.76.139#37679 (253.76.168.192.in-addr.arpa): query: 253.76.168.192.in-addr.arpa IN PTR + (192.168.76.1)
07-Sep-2022 09:23:32.690 client @0x7f93f800a3e0 192.168.76.139#37679 (254.76.168.192.in-addr.arpa): query: 254.76.168.192.in-addr.arpa IN PTR + (192.168.76.1)
07-Sep-2022 09:29:34.877 client @0x7f93f4030510 192.168.76.96#63128 (google.com): query: google.com IN A + (192.168.76.1)
07-Sep-2022 09:29:35.781 client @0x7f93fc070540 192.168.76.96#63129 (google.com): query: google.com IN AAAA + (192.168.76.1)
07-Sep-2022 09:29:38.098 client @0x7f93ec008360 192.168.76.96#63130 (google.com): query: google.com IN A + (192.168.76.1)
07-Sep-2022 09:29:38.130 client @0x7f93f4030510 192.168.76.96#63131 (google.com): query: google.com IN AAAA + (192.168.76.1)
```

Shortened and filtered tcpdump output showing the outgoing recursive lookup from a client request:

```
:~$ sudo tcpdump -i enp4s0 udp port 53
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on enp4s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
09:33:02.595825 IP <my-ext-ip>.40697 > dns.google.domain: 21779+% [1au] A? google.com. (51)
09:33:02.620007 IP dns.google.domain > <my-ext-ip>.40697: 21779 1/0/1 A 216.58.213.14 (55)
09:33:02.622853 IP <my-ext-ip>.37233 > <isp-dns-ip>.domain: 54096+ PTR? 4.4.8.8.in-addr.arpa. (38)
09:33:02.624007 IP <my-ext-ip>.57821 > dns.google.domain: 6972+% [1au] DS? com. (44)
09:33:02.632941 IP <isp-dns-ip>.domain > <my-ext-ip>.37233: 54096 1/0/0 PTR dns.google. (62)
09:33:02.633410 IP <my-ext-ip>.49292 > <isp-dns-ip>.domain: 52131+ PTR? 35.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (43)
09:33:02.642956 IP <isp-dns-ip>.domain > <my-ext-ip>.49292: 52131 NXDomain 0/0/0 (43)
09:33:02.648993 IP dns.google.domain > <my-ext-ip>.57821: 6972$ 2/0/1 DS, RRSIG (367)
09:33:02.655919 IP <my-ext-ip>.39385 > dns.google.domain: 44121+% [1au] DS? com. (44)
09:33:02.680136 IP dns.google.domain > <my-ext-ip>.39385: 44121$ 2/0/1 DS, RRSIG (367)
09:33:02.682891 IP <my-ext-ip>.58887 > <isp-dns-ip>.domain: 44625+% [1au] DS? com. (44)
09:33:02.692994 IP <isp-dns-ip>.domain > <my-ext-ip>.58887: 44625 1/0/1 DS (80)
09:33:02.696743 IP <my-ext-ip>.44152 > e.root-servers.net.domain: 44834 [1au] DS? com. (44)
09:33:02.714204 IP e.root-servers.net.domain > <my-ext-ip>.44152: 44834*- 2/0/1 DS, RRSIG (367)
... and so on for all root servers.
```

Comment: `SERVFAIL` should leave traces in your logfiles on what is happening. You can also increase loglevel.

Comment: Hi @PatrickMevzek, thanks for the sanity check. I have custom logging configured and I had everything turned up to 11, except I had 'lame servers' set to null. When I moved this back to the audit channel I was able to see the error, namely "broken trust chain resolving [X]" (it's staying in the audit channel now). As soon as I switched dnssec off ("dnssec-enable no; & dnssec-validation no;"), everything started working... now on to my next problem to figure out why DNSSSEC is broken.

Comment: OK... I'm flummoxed... I switched DNSSEC back on, and it's now working. I didn't do anything else. I explicitly disabled DNSSEC and validation, then re-enabled DNSSEC but left validation off, then on the next restart re-enabled validation and I am now getting the DNSKEYs successfully. I don't know why switching features off and on again (even though I had restarted the service AND the server before) fixed the problem, but it appears to have done so.

Comment: DNSSEC errors can indeed generate `SERVFAIL`... You can diagnose that often by doing the same query with `dig`, once with `+cd` flag once without. If the response code differs, the problem is most probably with DNSSEC. Of course it is not on/off that fixes the issue, you probably had a problem earlier like bind not being able to contact root to download/compare root keys or things like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My logging was set to ignore lame server errors. I set my lame server logging to  the audit channel to see the errors:

```
logging {
    channel audit_log {
                // Send the security related messages to a separate file.
                file "/var/log/named/named.log" versions 10 size 50m;
                severity info;
                print-time yes; 
        };
    category lame-servers { audit_log; };
};
```

I was then seeing errors like this:

```
07-Sep-2022 15:38:10.988 broken trust chain resolving 'something.com/DS/IN': 8.8.4.4#53
```

I switched off DNSSEC vailidation by setting the options `dnssec-enable no;` & `dnssec-validation no;`. I then re-enabed dnssec, restarted the server and did a couple of lookups, and then re-enabled validation.

Everything has been working since.